# Overlapping regex

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that matches any set of digits, with one possible dot. If there is another dot and more digits after it, do an overlapping match with the previous digits, the dot, and the following digits.
example string = `'aa323aa232.02.03.23.99aa87..0.111111.mm'`
desired results = `[323, 232.02, 02.03, 03.23, 23.99, 87, 0.111111]`

**currently using:**

```
import re
i = 'aa323aa232.02.03.23.99aa87..0.111111.mm'
matches = re.findall(r'(?=(\d+\.{0,1}\d+))', i)
print matches
```

**output:**

```
['323', '23', '232.02', '32.02', '2.02', '02.03', '2.03', '03.23', '3.23', '23.99', '3.99', '99', '87', '0.111111', '111111', '11111', '1111', '111', '11']
```

Comment: Is `99` not a result by itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This uses a lookahead assertion for capturing, and then another expression for gobbling characters following your rules:

```
>>> import re
>>> i = 'aa323aa232.02.03.23.99aa87..0.111111.mm'
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\d+(?:\.\d+(?!\.?\d))?', i)
```

Output

```
['323', '232.02', '02.03', '03.23', '23.99', '87', '0.111111']
```

Comment: +1 - Specifically, the Python solution would be `re.findall('(?=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\d+(?:\.\d+(?!\.?\d))?', i)` where `i` is the string.